# Which of those two is better way of avoiding mode hopping in laser?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser, photonics, laser-cavity

I'm supposed to design a laser cavity that would avoid mode hopping.

I have two projects in mind, and I did some simulations. The result for relative intensity of modes (no gain spectrum in account, yet) as a function of wavelength looks more/less like this:

[image]

I've read the [RP photonics encyclopedia](https://www.rp-photonics.com/mode_hopping.html), and it says that to avoid mode hopping, its good to have large FSR and/or to use a filter in the cavity.

So one of my designs (A) has a low relative intensity of the competing mode, but it is very close in the spectrum. The other design (B) has a strong competing mode, but it's far away. A is like employment of a filter, B is like using large FSR.

Which spectrum will cause less mode-hopping?

Comment: If you're allowed to add an etalon, the problem is solved.

Comment: @S.McGrew My cavity is supposed to serve a tuneable laser. I'm not sure if etalon will work. Can you elaborate?

Comment: An etalon is basically a flat glass plate inside the laser cavity.  It amounts to a separate resonator with its own mode spacing.  It is tuned by heating, tilting, etc., so that one mode corresponds to the laser cavity mode you want to isolate.

Comment: An alternative is to include a prism or grating in the cavity, *plus* an etalon, if you need a wider tuning range.

Comment: @S.McGrew I appreciate your technical tips, but I just can just implement the two designs I presented. No much space for modifications. So my question is just which spectrum gives more hope for modehopping avoidance.